# Check if contract is destructed

Tags: solidity, javascript, selfdestruct

Once a contract is no longer valid (eg after calling selfdestruct on it), one can still call functions on it although the contract won't behave as expected. In javascript, how can one check if the contract has been destructed before performing a transaction?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can call `getCode` (`web3.eth.getCode(address)`). The call will return 0x if it selfdestruct'd. Note that this isn't a positive way to know it selfdestruct'd, it'll also return 0x if it's an EOA or the contract was created with no code.